# Redirect to subfolder with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a .htaccess-file that redirect requests of example.com or www.example.com to: https://example.com/game1
But I can't get it to work.

I have this in my .htaccess:

```
# ReDirect to current instance of game
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != On
SetEnvIf PAGE_PATH "game1"
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%{ENV:PAGE_PATH}/$1 [R,L]
```

The PAGE_PATH variable does not work and if I use setup2 apache changes the URL but the redirect fails and I can't call the correct URL either. I get error: example.com redirected you too many times (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS).

Setup2 for .htaccess:

```
# ReDirect to current instance of game
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != On
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/game1/ [R,L]
```

How can I configure my desired behavior?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1/game1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

This will redirect :

```
example.com
```

or

```
www.example.com
```

to

```
https://example.com/game1/
```

Comment: When I try your suggested configuration i get the same error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS and my URL get changed to : "https://example.com/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/game1/"

Comment: Useless. This will cause infinite redirects.

Comment: @Walf could you please explain how this will cause infinite redirect?

Comment: @Walf this is a pre tested rule and works fine on my apache server. This doesnt cause infinite loop as the destination url is diffrent.

Comment: Perhaps I misread your code but it looks like it will either be infinite, or fail to redirect a5 all if the use is already on the the correct, secured domain.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(?>/?)(?!game[1-9]\d*(?:$|/))(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%{ENV:PAGE_PATH}/$1 [R,L]
```

It will only redirect if the URL *does not* start with `/gameN/` where `N` is any whole number. It first puts the slash in a once-only subpattern so, if matched, it cannot be "unmatched" by backtracking and break the next part. The next part is a negative look-ahead assertion.

Separate out the domain and https checks and place them before the game path redirect, since they should be permanent redirects whereas game should be temporary. You're better off hard-coding the domain in that check since `SERVER_NAME` is affected by [UseCanonicalName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#usecanonicalname) which is off by default. Replace `localhost` with your dev server's domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:localhost|example\.com)$
RewriteRule .* https://example.com/$0 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^off$
RewriteRule .* https//%{SERVER_NAME}/$0 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: When I try this I get: ".htaccess: RewriteCond: unknown flag 'L'" and if I put it in a subdir to localhost, that dir does not even get listed for "index Of". I am also curious of how to get the PAGE_PATH variable to work, now I just replaced it with "game1".

Comment: I mistyped `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Did you mean to use `SetEnv`?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a custom variable 'PAGE_PATH' and I thought I could use "SetEnv" for that.

Comment: I can't get the rules with 'R=301' to work, when I try I get a loop-behavior.

Comment: But the rule: "RewriteRule ^(?>/?)(?!game[1-9]\d*(?:$|/))(.*) http://example.com/game1/$1 [R,L]" works great!

Comment: Try inverting https check `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$`

Comment: You will have to look in the network panel of your browser's debugger so you can see what redirects you're actually receiving.